# Show Query plan in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sql-execution-plan

Is it possible to display the query plan graphically in a  report in SSRS 2005/2008 as it shows in SSMS?

Any ideas, references, articles would be apperciated.

Comment: Any notes on why you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen a way to directly display a query plan.  The few times I've wanted to do something similar I just copied the query out of SSRS & pasted it into a query window in SSMS.  SSMS is a lot easier to use for designing/debugging queries.  Once I have the query down it's a small matter to paste it back into SSRS.  (I have to declare my parameters and set values to them, but that's not a big deal).